# WAS Liberty & Atmosphere long-polling 1 min delay

Tags: long-polling, atmosphere, websphere-liberty

I have been testing Atmosphere on WAS Liberty, and it is all working fine on Liberty 8.5.5.4.

When I try to upgrade to Liberty 8.5.5.5 or 8.5.5.6, there is a 1 min delay on the initial connection.

The problem can be easily replicated by downloading the atmosphere-chat-2.3.3.war from maven central. Rename to atmosphere-chat.war, change the `application.js` to have `transport = 'long-polling'`. Copy modified war in liberty dropins folder. Start server, go to http://localhost:9080/atmosphere-chat/

I think this might be a bug with async processing in Liberty, but maybe the Atmosphere or IBM guys know better. I can't quite figure it out, so I am staying on 8.5.5.4 for now.

If anyone can shed some light. It would be great.

Comment: And I have tried adding <variable name="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.async-supported" value="true"/> into the liberty server.xml

Comment: I also just tried with Liberty 8.5.5.7. Same problem, takes 60 seconds to connect the first time. Is there anywhere I can file a bug with IBM?

Comment: Can you get a javacore 30 seconds in and pastebin the stack traces?  and/or maybe  a web container / TCP channel trace?

<logging  traceSpecification="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer*=all:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer*=all:HTTPChannel=all"
traceFileName="trace.log"
maxFileSize="200"
maxFiles="10"
traceFormat="BASIC" />

Comment: find attached at https://gist.github.com/seamusmac/277992f03165034ec459#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: there is 2 30 second delays right after: 
18:55:03:581 BST] 00000047 HttpServiceCo <  destroy Exit and
[10/10/15 18:54:33:044 BST] 0000002c IRequestImpl  3   true

Comment: I just tried Liberty 8.5.5.8, and done a little bit more debugging. 

It seems that the buffer is NOT flushed properly in HttpOutputStreamImpl

HttpOutputStreamImpl.ignoreFlush is true,

Comment: I get the following in the ibm trace logs  "HttpOutputStr 3   Ignoring first flush attempt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting

```
AtmosphereConfig.PROPERTY_USE_STREAM=false
```

works around the issue for now.